# Why UIWebView work so slowly when loadHTMLString with UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

It take about 10s to `loadHTMLString` in my APP, who can point out what's the problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, SCREEN_WIDTH, 480)];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [webView setOpaque:NO];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:webView];
}
```

After enter the view, If I receive message:

```
- (void)updateJournalView:(NSArray *)journals {
    NSString *descHtml = [self getHtmlDesc:journals];
    [webView loadHTMLString:descHtml baseURL:nil];
 }
```

`getHtmlDesc` method will return the html string quickly.

from load log, you can see it take about 5s to load.

2012-11-26 20:34:35.322 test[8456:c07] ====start load 2012-11-26 12:34:35 +0000:

2012-11-26 20:34:39.890 test[8456:c07] ====finish load 2012-11-26 12:34:39 +0000:

Following is UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
 CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
 frame.size.height = 1;
 aWebView.frame = frame;
 CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
 frame.size = fittingSize;
 aWebView.frame = frame;
 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, fittingSize.height);
 NSLog(@"====finish load %@:", [NSDate date]);
}

  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest    *)request
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  NSURL *url = [request URL];
  if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"redirect"] &&
  [[url host] isEqualToString:@"opp_detail"]) {
  NSString *oppIdStr = [[url path] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/player_id=" withString:@""];
  if (oppIdStr && [oppIdStr length]) {
    NSNumber *oppId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[oppIdStr intValue]];
    if ([oppId intValue] != gcontext.me.id) {
      [screenNav gotoOppDetailScreen:[oppId intValue]];
    }
  }
 }
 return YES;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
 NSURL *url = [request URL];
 if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"redirect"] &&
  [[url host] isEqualToString:@"opp_detail"]) {
  NSString *oppIdStr = [[url path] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/player_id="   withString:@""];
 if (oppIdStr && [oppIdStr length]) {
  NSNumber *oppId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[oppIdStr intValue]];
  if ([oppId intValue] != gcontext.me.id) {
    [screenNav gotoOppDetailScreen:[oppId intValue]];
  }
}
}
return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
  NSLog(@"====start load %@:", [NSDate date]);
}
```

Please give me a hand, why it is so slow when `loadHTMLString` with `UIWebView`?

Comment: Please don't add webView in ScrollView because WebView Default contain ScrollView. If content is to long to represent in visible webView size then webView will automatically use ScrollView to represent content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is nothing heavy to render, then it's possible that all about slow disk operations, that are performing when you're reading your html string.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3400892/1851930